# Как реализовать remote: true для react (rails)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Создаю форму таким образом:

```
= form_for Review.new do |f|
  = react_component "Popups/ReviewPopup", {name: "review-popup"}
```

Внутри `Popups/ReviewPopup` у меня поля формы с нужными `name`.
И при клике на сабмит происходит:

```
<button
    onClick={e => {
      onClick(e);
      e.preventDefault();
    }}
    className="button popup-footer__button"
  >
    Отправить
</button>
```

После чего, без перезагрузки, должны отправляться данные из формы и показаться сообщение в браузере.

В общем-то при обычной отправке (если закомментировать `onClick(e); e.preventDefault();`) все работает прекрасно. Но не совсем понятно как реализовывать `remote: true`. Причем хотелось бы реализовать именно поведение `remote: true`, а не отлавливать при клике данные из полей и отправлять их с помощью `axios` на сервер.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`remote: true` просто добавляет `data-remote` в форму. А *jquery rails* добавляет *ajax* к формам (и ссылкам), где есть `data-remote`.

На мой взгляд лучше воспользоваться возможностями *react* и попробовать реализовать функционал через *axios*.

Но если очень хочется, то можно добавить библиотеку `rails-ujs`.

```
import Rails from 'rails-ujs';
```

И для отправки формы:

```
Rails.fire("my_element", 'submit');
```

Вот [тут](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29546) может быть более подробно описано.

Comment: я в итоге и реализовал через axios, спасибо.